# Could not pass custom parameters while loading paginated reports in powerbi javascript api

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-api

Goal: Load a paginated report into webpage which has few parameters with the help of powerbi api javascript.

Paginated reportUrl:
https://app.powerbi.com/groups/workspaceId/rdlreports/reportId?ctid=something&rp:CustomerID=something&rp:ContractID=something

I can load the report but could not pass the parameters - hence report is loading as blank.

UnLike powerbi report, paginated report doesn't support report.getFilters() like powerBi embedded report.

I referred these docs - but could not find any help...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports-parameters
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/paginated-reports-row-level-security#passing-the-configured-parameter-using-the-embed-token
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-paginated-reports-customers

This is how I am getting a powerbi report and then embeding that in webpage:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("AccessToken")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetEmbeddedAccessTokenAsync(string reportType)
    {            

        Guid currentReportId = getCurrentReportId(reportType); //private method which gets the report guid

        using (var client = await GetPowerBIClientAsync())
        {                
            var report = await client.Reports.GetReportInGroupAsync(_powerBiWorkspaceId, currentReportId);
        


            var generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: TokenAccessLevel.View);

            var tokenResponse = await client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroupAsync(_powerBiWorkspaceId, report.Id, generateTokenRequestParameters);
            
            return new OkObjectResult(JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { EmbedUrl = report.EmbedUrl, AccessToken = tokenResponse.Token, WorkspaceId = _powerBiWorkspaceId, ReportId = report.Id, Expires = tokenResponse.Expiration }));
        }
    }
    
    
    let token = await this.http.get(this.url + 'api/PowerBi/AccessToken?reportType=' + this.reportType, { params: {}, responseType: 'text', withCredentials: true }).toPromise();
    let tokenObject = JSON.parse(token);
    let reportContainer = document.getElementById('kpi-report-container');
    this.powerbi.bootstrap(reportContainer, config);
    let report: Report = <Report>(this.powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config));
    
    // Report.off removes a given event handler if it exists.        
    report.off("loaded");
    let self = this;
    // Report.on will add an event handler which prints to Log window.
    report.on("loaded", function () {
      self.SelectedReportId(self.reportId);
      report.updateSettings({
        bookmarksPaneEnabled: false,
        filterPaneEnabled: true
      });
      // Set token expiration listener
      self.SetTokenExpirationListener(tokenObject.Expires,
        2, /*minutes before expiration*/
        tokenObject.ReportId,
        tokenObject.WorkspaceId);
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

We can pass the URL parameters into an embedded Paginated Report by concatenating the parameters with the embed URL.

For example:
If we have a parameter named "Salesperson" which has one of its values as "Brownie", then we can filter the Paginated report by concatenating it in the embed URL of the report within report config:
embedUrl + "&rp:Salesperson=Brownie"

The above embedUrl will filter the embedded paginated report as per the given parameter.

You can refer this [blog link](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/embed-paginated-reports-in-your-own-application-for-your-customers-preview/) for more information.